# Throw error when multiple elements with same ID are added to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, reactjs, typescript

I'm working in a react/typescript stack and just spent a half hour debugging an issue caused by two HTML elements with the same id on the page.

Is there some way to get react or chrome to warn or throw an error when this happens in the future?

Comment: not sure but https://validator.w3.org/ validation service will definitely warn you if there are same id's or any other not-allowed HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add a validator such as [html-validator-cli](https://github.com/zrrrzzt/html-validator-cli) to your continuous integration system (npm, gulp, grunt, whatever), ideally setup to watch your code for changes and trigger execution of the validator on change. Some watch solutions for: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-watch), [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch).

Sample output catching duplicate ID from html-validator-cli [tests](https://github.com/zrrrzzt/html-validator/blob/cafcb9baa9984c4390ffbe181e0bdc7713b74628/test/data/errors.txt):

```
Warning: Empty heading.
16  From line 882, column 1; to line 882, column 4
17  Error: Duplicate ID “tinymce”.
18  From line 952, column 22; to line 952, column 56
```